# Reading saved email file with “.msg” extension, in local disk

Tags: python, email, parsing

How to read email file (saved email to local drive, with “.msg” extension)?

I tried this 2 lines and it doesn't work out.

```
msg = open('Departure  HOUSTON EXPRESS  Port  NORFOLK.msg', 'r')
print msg.read()
```

I searched the web for an answer, which gave the below code:

```
import email
def read_MSG(file):
    email_File = open(file)
    messagedic = email.Message(email_File)
    content_type = messagedic["plain/text"]
    FROM = messagedic["From"]
    TO = messagedic.getaddr("To")
    sujet = messagedic["Subject"]
    email_File.close()
    return content_type, FROM, TO, sujet


myMSG= read_MSG(r"c:\\myemail.msg")
print myMSG
```

However it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\G.py", line 19, in <module>
myMSG= read_MSG(r"c:\\myemail.msg")
File "C:\Python27\G.py", line 10, in read_MSG
messagedic = email.Message(email_File)
TypeError: 'LazyImporter' object is not callable
```

Some responses on Internet tell it’d better to convert the .msg to .eml before parsing but I am not really sure how.

What would be the best way to read a .msg file?

Comment: What's the full traceback in the error message?

Comment: thanks, John Zwinck. please see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have now looks to be completely unworkable for what you're trying to accomplish.  You need to parse Outlook ".msg" files, which [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491152/parsing-msg-eml-files-with-python-2-7) in Python but not using the `email` module.  But if you can use ".eml" files as you mentioned, it will be easier because the `email` module can read those.

To read .eml files, see [email.message_from_file()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file).

Comment: thanks, Mr. Zwinck. by the way, how can I convert ".msg" to ".eml"?

Comment: I don't know, you already said you found resources online explaining how to do that.  Or maybe Outlook can do it.  Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this like me, almost a decade after the original question:

After trying some different solutions offered here and elsewhere on the internet, I found that the easiest for me was to use [extract-msg](https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor), which you can install with pip. The readme documentation is limited, but the doc-strings in the actual library is quite comprehensive.

In my case, I needed to read a .msg on disc and specifically save its attachments to disc. Here is some sample code to show how easy this is with extact-msg:

```
import extract_msg

msg = extract_msg.openMsg('c:/some_folder/some_mail.msg')
sender = msg.sender
subject = msg.subject
body = msg.body
time_received = msg.receivedTime  # datetime
attachment_filenames = []
for att in msg.attachments:
    att.save(customPath='c:/saved_attachments/')
    attachment_filenames.append(att.name)
```

Comment: fantastic! thank you for the amazing sharing! spirits like your make this world so warm and beautiful! just btw, there's only "AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'time_received'" :)

Comment: @MarkK , aw thanks for the warm words :) Yep: looks like I used the wrong attribute in my sample code. Should be `receivedTime` not `time_received`, thanks for the heads-up. I fixed it in the post.